# Dynamically display formatted value in f.text_field without JavaScript

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

In the database, prices are stored in cents, and it's easy to *display* them in the proper format, but when I try to use the `text_field` helper, there doesn't appear to be a way to format the money in the input's value without Javascript.

```html
<%= form_with model: @item, local: true do |f| %>
...
  <div class="flex flex-col mb-3">
    <%= f.label :price, 'Price' %>
    <%= f.text_field :price, type:'number' %>
  </div>
...
<% end %>
```

Are there any ways to do this in plain HTML/Ruby, and if not, are there any simple JavaScript workarounds using the built-in Stimulus library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that by not exposing the original, cent-based value in the form, but by using a custom dollar-based attribute.

```
# in app/models/item.rb
def price_in_dollars
  '%.2f' % (price / 100.0)
end

def price_in_dollars=(string)
  self.price = (string.to_f * 100).round
end
```

and use that attribute in the form like this:

```
<%= form_with model: @item, local: true do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="flex flex-col mb-3">
    <%= f.label :price, 'Price' %>
    <%= f.text_field :price_in_dollars, type: 'number' %>
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Note: You will need to add `price_in_dollars` to the strong parameters in your controller too.

Comment: When I added `:price_in_dollars` to the strong parameters list, it tries to save it into the database, and the column does not exist, so it throws an error. Is there any way to make the `:price_in_dollars` field get assigned to the `:price` column in the database?

Comment: I fixed my answer. I forgot to assign to `self.price =` in the `price_in_dollars=(string)` method.

Comment: The setter is not being invoked when `@item.assign_attributes` is being called, so it's still trying to set `:price_in_dollars`.

Comment: It should call `price_in_dollars=`, not the original method. What does the request look like and your strong parameters?

Comment: Strong parameters: `params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :description, :rate, :rate_in_dollars)`

Request: `{"_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "item"=>{"name"=>"Item 1", "description"=>"The first item.", "price_in_dollars"=>"20.3"},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "id"=>"7"}`

Comment: In your form, the attribute is named `price_in_dollars` and the method in the model is named `price_in_dollars` too. But the strong params permit an attribute named `rate_in_dollars`. That is the issue, because the attribute has to be named the same in all places. Additionally, the strong params require a `topic`, but you said the form is for a `item`. That needs to be fixed too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `text_field`, try using [`number_field_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag) with a [step attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step) specified.

```
<%= f.number_field_tag :price, nil, step: 0.01 %>
# => <input id="price" name="price" step="0.01" type="number" />
```